# Editing Help Page

Tags: support

From where is the page on [editing help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) visible? This is a very basic page which should be available to anyone asking a question. Yet it was only after considerable effort that I came across this page. Searching for editing help in the search box didnt help too.

Comment: Whenever you ask a question, there should be a toolbar at the top of the panel where you type your questions. Click on the rightmost button with the question mark...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J.M. directed you to the "Ask Question" page, and to a question mark symbol. However this question mark exists in every **answer** edit box.

It is the rightmost button of the toolbar.

Comment: Somehow my interpretation was that he was about to ask a question and couldn't find the editing help while he was typing it. But yeah, every question/answer panel does have that button... :D